Optional generic select function for useObservable hook in react
I have custom generic hook for rxjs observables. Now it looks like this:
type Params<T> = {
  observable$: Observable<T> | null;
  next: (value: T) => void;
};

export const useSubscription = <T>({
  observable$,
  next,
}: Params<T>) => {
  const nextCallback = useCallbackRef(next);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!observable$) {
      return undefined;
    }

    const sub = observable$.subscribe(nextCallback);

    return () => sub.unsubscribe();
  }, [observable$, nextCallback]);
};

It works ok, but now I'm trying to add optional generic select function to Params. I'm planning to use it with rxjs map operator. select should take T as input and return some type R, which then passed to the next function. If select is not provided, then next's input type should be T as before. So options for possible params roughly should look like this:
type Params<T, R> = {
  observable$: Observable<T> | null;
  next: (value: T) => void;
} | {
  observable$: Observable<T> | null;
  next: (value: R) => void;
  select: (value: T) => R;
};

I tried to accomplish this with conditional types, function overloads, but couldn't make this work.

See below for some explanation:
type ParamsA<T> = {
  observable$: T;
  next: (value: T) => void;
  select?: null;
}

type ParamsB<T, R> = {
  observable$: T;
  next: (value: R) => void;
  select: (value: T) => R;
}

type Params<T, R = undefined> = R extends undefined ? ParamsA<T> : ParamsB<T, R>;

const a: Params<number> = {
  observable$: 1,
  next: (value) => { console.log(value); },
} // OK: value --> number

const b: Params<number, string> = {
  observable$: 1,
  next: (value) => { console.log(value); },
} // ERROR: Property 'select' is missing in type '{ observable$: number; next: (value: string) => void; }' but required in type 'ParamsB<number, string>'

const c: Params<number, string> = {
  observable$: 1,
  next: (value) => { console.log(value); },
  select: (value) => 'a',
} // OK: next value --> string, select value --> number

const d: Params<number> = {
  observable$: 1,
  next: (value) => { console.log(value); },
  select: (value) => 'a',
} // ERROR: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'select' does not exist in type 'ParamsA<number>'.

So we separate Params into the two possible forms it can take and use conditional types to determine which one based on whether or not a generic parameter R has been passed into. By setting the default value of the R parameter to undefined it becomes optional, in turn making the select property only required when R is passed.
Edit:
You can add an optional parameter to ParamsA of select?: undefined to support destructuring. You can also then use the select parameter to disambiguate the union type in your code.
export const useSubscription  = <T, R = undefined>(props: Params<T, R>) => {
    const { observable$, next, select } = props;
    if (select) {
      props.select(); // props is inferred to be ParamsB
    }
}


Thank you for your reply!
When I use such Params union in the hook and try to destructure params object, Typescript complaints that select doesn't exist on type Params.
Also, is it possible to use inference here without passing type arguments? For example, if I call useSubscription({ observable$: obs, next: (value) => {...} }) then the value type is inferred as T(if obs is of type Observable). And if I call useSubscription with select function provided, then value type in next callback is inferred as type which is returned from select.

Added small change to support destructuring and disambiguation in a use of the Params type

Although destructuring works great now, it is still not possible to use useSubscription hook without providing type arguments.
